# Linux and Window DFS shares - restoring previous versions of files/folders

Tags: linux, windows, windows-server-2008, dfs, dfs-r

I know I can mount DFS shares on my Linux boxes with no issues, but is there a method by which I can access/restore previous versions of folders/files from these DFS shares?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The previous versions feature relies on "shadow copies", which is a Windows/NTFS feature which allows for the storage of multiple versions of a file. While this is available automatically on the client side for Windows Vista/7, older versions required you to install a "Shadow Copy Client" so that you could view these in Windows Explorer.

Unfortunately there is no Shadow Copy Client available for non-Windows systems.

Answer (score 0):

The is an early version of a library to access "volume shadow copies" called [libvshadow](https://github.com/libyal/libvshadow).